# Call AngularJS directive from controller on click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-directive, angular-directive

Quick question, so I'm using [tg-dynamic-directive](https://github.com/thgreasi/tg-dynamic-directive) to loop through a json file and output following tree. (See image attached)

[image: Json Tree]

So the problem is, when the "tree" gets very long there are some serious performance problems because the browser needs to render a lot of items. (I'm talking about 1000 or longer). So what I'm trying to do is initially only load first 2 levels and the rest will be collapsed. When a user clicks expand arrow of each element I need to render its children. (If that makes sense). So basically run tg-dynamic-directive again.

When page starts rendering and function that returns template with the html is fired I have this to check if its first 2 levels:

```
$scope.getView = function (item) {

        // Check if item is defined
        if(typeof item != 'undefined') {

            // Load course, label and module first!
            if(item.type == 'course' || item.type == 'label' || item.type == 'module' || item.type == 'course_assessment' || item.type == 'module_assessment') {
                // Return Template
                return 'nestable_item.html';
            } else {
                // Otherwise return null
                return null;
            }
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    };
```

Then what I need to do is call that directive again when expand arrow is clicked.

This is the directive:

```
angular.module('tg.dynamicDirective', [])
    .directive('tgDynamicDirective', ['$compile',
        function($compile) {
            'use strict';

            function templateUrlProvider(getView, ngModelItem) {
                if (getView) {
                    if (typeof getView === 'function') {
                        var templateUrl = getView(ngModelItem) || '';
                        if (templateUrl) {
                            return templateUrl;
                        }
                    } else if (typeof getView === 'string' && getView.length) {
                        return getView;
                    }
                }
                return '';
            }

            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                require: '^ngModel',
                scope: true,
                template: '<div ng-include="templateUrl"></div>',
                link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

                    scope.$watch(function() {
                        var ngModelItem = scope.$eval(attrs.ngModel);
                        var getView = scope.$eval(attrs.tgDynamicDirectiveView);
                        scope.ngModelItem = ngModelItem;
                        return templateUrlProvider(getView, ngModelItem);
                    }, function(newValue, oldValue) {
                        scope.templateUrl = newValue;
                    });
                }
            };
        }
    ]);
```

My question is how can I fire tg-dynamic-directive again when expand arrow is clicked from the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$rootScope.broadcast("XXXXXX");` and catch it

```
$rootScope.$on("XXXXXX", function() {
    // function call
})
```

in directive and call the function you want.
or
use document.createElement("tg-dynamic-directive");